# Create a heatmap of ratio

Tags: r, ggplot2

everyone! I am new to R and would like to create a heatmap.
There is a data set with columns:

- X: x coordinate
- Y: y coordinate
- Pet_type: type of pet (cat, dog, hamster, etc)
- Owner_type: type of owner (adult male, adult female, kid)

Small dataset:

| Owner | Pet | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Male | Dog | 27.793 | 88.2128 |
| Male | Hamster | 37.7177 | 87.9776 |
| Female | Cat | 24.4547 | 87.3016 |
| Kid | Cat | 36.464 | 84.9169 |
| Kid | Dog | 29.4175 | 84.5433 |
| Female | Lizard | 37.9588 | 83.9029 |
| Male | Guinea pig | 44.8986 | 82.7822 |
| Kid | Dog | 26.6216 | 82.0757 |
| Male | Hamster | 46.2332 | 81.9817 |
| Male | Cat | 31.9716 | 81.7507 |
| Female | Cat | 22.8606 | 80.9761 |
| Kid | Dog | 29.744 | 80.7988 |
| Kid | Lizard | 32.2393 | 80.35 |
| Female | Guinea pig | 38.92 | 78.8604 |
| Male | Dog | 39.42 | 78.3604 |
| Kid | Hamster | 32.2632 | 87.8267 |

What would be the steps to create a heatmap which shows the ratio of one specific pet vs all pets in that specific bin?
For example: I want to create a heatmap of Cats density and if the bin consists of 20 pets and 10 of those are cats - the bin's value is 0,5 or 50%, etc.

I am using ggplot and I got that far that I can see count of total pets in each bin.
What manipulations should I do to the table, before feeding it to ggplot?

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(X, Y))+
  geom_bin_2d(bins=15)
```

[image: This is how far I got]

I am struggling to understand how to create a statement that I want to see Cats vs all pets ratio in all bins.

So yeah, I would really appreciate if someone could help me with this problem (probably an easy one)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please consider posting a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: In addition to try and provide a reproducible example, I think as a general rule the best way to start is to first calculate the values you want to plot (ratio of pets in bins), get the results in tidy format and then worry about plotting.

Comment: @yoland I added a small dataset sample, what would be the steps needed before ggplot?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do 2-D binning. One option is to can get {ggplot2} to make the bins for you and then normalize to the total count and re-plot it. Here you first built the plot using raw count and then pull out the calculated bins using `ggplot2::ggplot_build()` and do a standard `group_by() %>% mutate(fract = x/sum(x)`. Then you can re-plot.

```r
library(tidyverse)

n <- 5000

d <- tibble(x = rnorm(n),
            y = rnorm(n),
            pet = fct_infreq(sample(
              c("cat", "dog", "fish", "bird"), n, T, prob = c(4, 3, 2, 1)
            )))
p <- d %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
  geom_bin_2d(aes(fill = after_stat(count))) +
  facet_wrap( ~ pet)

# original plot of count per animal per bin
p
```

[image]

```r
# get underlying data
e <- ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]]

# normalize and then re-plot
e %>% 
  mutate(pet = fct_recode(PANEL, cat = "1", dog = "2", fish = "3", bird = "4")) %>% 
  group_by(xbin, ybin) %>% 
  mutate(fract = count/sum(count)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(xmin, ymin)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = fract)) +
  facet_wrap(~pet)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>